# Atom hydrogen: how to switch kernel start path

Tags: atom-editor, hydrogen

Open Atom, start local ipython kernel then run codes in a file. Hydrogen starts the kernel in the file's directory. After it finishes, I want to restart the kernel and run another file in another directory. But hydrogen keeps the kernel path to the first file.

Is there a way to "run file" in hydrogen, ie to start a new kernel under the files directory and run all lines in the file? (Like what spyder does)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this will help, but you might try:

Settings
→ Packages
→ Hydrogen
→ Settings
→ Directory to start the kernel in: Current directory of the file.

Then, run your first file, shut down kernel and run the second file.